# exposing port 80 using kubernetes on gcloud?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I was able to expose port 80 before, just last month, using kubernetes and google containers.
But now simple service example like this doesn't work anymore:

```
{
    "kind":"Service",
    "apiVersion":"v1",
    "metadata":{
        "name":"check",
        "labels":{
            "app":"check"
        }
    },
    "spec":{
       "type": "LoadBalancer",
       "ports": [
       {
           "port":80,
           "name":"check-server"
       }
       ],
       "selector":{
           "app":"check"
       }
    }
}
```

and this works:

```
{
    "kind":"Service",
    "apiVersion":"v1",
    "metadata":{
        "name":"check",
        "labels":{
            "app":"check"
        }
    },
    "spec":{
       "type": "LoadBalancer",
       "ports": [
       {
           "port":8080,
           "name":"check-server"
       }
       ],
       "selector":{
           "app":"check"
       }
    }
}
```

does anyone know what changed in google cloud?

Comment: For those trying to figure out what the difference between the two files is,
"port":80 changed to "port":8080

Comment: Can you tell us exactly what error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your pods are exposing port 8080? then you are missing `targetPort`

```
   "ports": [
   {
       "port":80,
       "targetPort": "8080",
       "name":"check-server"
   }
```